# How can I Covert a string into format of "BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY"

Tags: python, rsa

I am simulating to login a website, and the server feed back a "pubkey" for RSA Encryption.  I should encrypt my password with the "pubkey". The content is:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDWgW3gsfqzrID7Bz+pfcHD1TMP
CFAE0/1fnJnPDumXD6p75LTCpkA1jxVFpunLqIgKtSr8M84z5dyX4QQ9Rtb4tcd6
3ptgQZkoIGqrVdwskL8pSkTjI6zkG4ebB5UmlNiRQw7TcwmufOfYfAS94PGZaDxH
wFGtMyOvP2UXBxduMwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Now, the question is I failed to convert it into the format "RSAPublicKey"   with the rsa package of python2.7.8.

ERROR CODE:

```
key = rsa.key.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(self.publickey["pubkey"].encode("utf-8"), "PEM")
```

ERROR HINT:

```
ValueError: No PEM start marker "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----" found
```

I would use the right "rsapublickey" for:

```
password_rsaed = base64.b64encode(rsa.encrypt(self.password.encode("utf-8"), key))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'va got a method to solve the problem. It's :

```
rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1_openssl_pem(cls, keyfile)
```

It loads a PKCS#1.5 PEM-encoded public key file from OpenSSL, and can recognize the content starting with "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", and return a publickey object.

```
print(type(self.publickey["pubkey"].encode("utf-8")))
key = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1_openssl_pem(self.publickey["pubkey"].encode("utf-8"))
print(type(key))
```

RESULTS:

```
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'rsa.key.PublicKey'>
```

TIPS：
    The method are from python3.